# StructureMap for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, structuremap

Has anyone tried to port the current StructureMap source to work with Silverlight? I know there are other IOC containers for Silverlight like Unity, Ninject, and a few others, but I particularly like the ease of use with StrutureMap.

Anyways, I'm on a quest at the moment to get it working with SL.

Let me know your thoughts if this is really worth doing? Seems like something fun to do.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this does not help you immediately but I work with Structure Map's author Jeremy Miller. He asked me to relay to you that **Structure Map 3.0 is coming along and will have Silverlight support**. His guess as to when it would be ready was "in the July timeframe."

Comment: FYI Structure Map 3.0 has been pushed out and as of now is still not on the horizon.

Answer (score 0):

Very cool. Probably no need to do what I'm doing now then. I'm guessing Jeremy will change alot of the older xml to use more LINQ. I ran into some issues with serialization so I'm excited to see what Jeremy will do.